# Ubuntu 22.04 LTS: Constant audio cracking when XM-1000M3 is connected

Tags: sound, headphones

Whenever I'm playing music, my headphones start to audio crack with the `high fidelity playback (a2dp sink)` turned on as the main setting. I've tested this issue on and `20.4 LTS` and `21.04 LTS` and I can hear the audio crystal clear. To add, audio works perfectly fine when the headphones are disconnected.

**System**
Dell XPS 13 9310

`Linux fsociety 5.15.0-39-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Any clue on what's going on and how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Changing the Codec to SBC from LDAC (High Quality) in PulseAudio fixes the issue

Comment: How do you change the codec?

Comment: I installed the PulseAudio Pulse Control App and navigated to Configuration and selected the name of my headphones and switched to Codec. Hope this helps